# Rethrowing an exception causes my data to not save

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, exception, nservicebus

I have this code:

```
catch (Exception e)
{
    try
    {
        transmitModel.AddAck(transmitBatchId,
          "<error><message>" + e.Message + "</message><stack>" + e.StackTrace +
          "</stack><Location>FromLisAtOMServer<Location>" +
          "<TransmitBatchId>" + message.TransmitBatchId +
          "</TransmitBatchId></error>", false, true);
    }
    // If we fail to log, we don't want that to bubble up... 
    // We want the real error to do that.
    catch (Exception){}

    // Re-throw the exception so that the service bus will 
    // move this off to the error queue.);
    throw;
}
```

The AddAck method will save that string to the database (Using Entity Framework).

When I run this without the last statement `throw`, it saves my error message to database fine.

When I have the `throw;` in there, it says it saves  but when I query the database it is not in there.  I can even run a entity query via my data context right after saving (in the code) and it returns the value as if it is saved (though that may be using a cached version).  But if I go and query afterwards the data is not there....

I have checked to be sure that no other logic is causing the value to be removed on an exception.

Any ideas what could be causing this?

Comment: Sounds something like you didn't commit the db transaction?

Comment: But where is the code which commits the log to db?

Comment: Isn't the transaction getting rolled back by a finally statement somewhere up the stack?

Comment: Are you really saving XML into your database instead of populating columns or is that a service call?

Comment: @SimonWang - Post as an answer and I will accept.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, post as an answer here, it comes in my mind very easily as I used to met the same issue, and figured out it was just caused I didn't commit the DB transaction.
Thanks, :)

Answer (score 0):

This call is as a result of an NServiceBus message.

I forgot that my NServiceBus stuff runs in a distributed transaction.  So when I threw the exception it roll back all my pending changes.

I need to find out how to get this log file to post outside the transaction...

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that NServiceBus provides hooks for this kind of thing.

Your problem is quite possibly what you have stated: the message handling *has* to happen in a transaction.  You *cannot* commit that else you are also committing errors.  So you definitely have to find out where you can hook into the post message handling exception processing.

With Shuttle ESB (http://shuttle.codeplex.com/) we use pipelines for handling different use cases and you can hook into the PipelineException event that is raised by the various pipelines.  Shuttle has a the ability for developers to add modules that hook into the various events.  There is already a `SystemExceptionModule` that does more-or-less what you want to do.